# django views.py to call another python script

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm new to Django. Please help me with the below.

I have a User form who provides URL1 and URL2.. These URLs need to be passed to another Python script[`redirects.py`] which will do the Validation to check whether they are in a valid URL format and return the Message to the User.

Now my question is how to write my `views.py` so as to get this done. I got to know that we can import the `redirects.py` in my `views.py` and call it. But I'm not aware of how to print the messages in my browser. Please help. Let me know if any more info is required.

```
def shortcuts_process(request):
    print request.POST
    return HttpResponse("Source is %s\nDestination is %s" % (request.POST['source'],request.POST['destination']))
```

**Update :**
This is my script overview. I have got a python script[`redirects.py`] in my system which accepts Source and Destination URLs. Once accepted, it validates whether they are in URL format, then takes backup, then add them into `.htaccess` and display the line added to the file. While doing all this, it keeps intimating the User with the information on whats happening in the script.

Now I have made the django to create a web portal which provides the User to input source and Destination. Now i want to call the script from `views.py` and print all those `redirects.py` Script output in User's web browser.

Please help me in getting this, I have spent an entire day looking for this answer. Thanks.

`Update 2:`
Please let me know why the below is not getting displayed in my browser

From `views.py`

```
def shortcuts_process(request):
 if 'source' in request.POST and 'destination' in request.POST and request.POST['source'] and request.POST['destination']:
            src=request.POST['source']
            desti= request.POST['destination']
            my_result=process_input(src,desti)
            return render_to_response('results.html',{'result': my_result}
```

From `results.html` :

```
<html>    
<head>
This is the result page to User
</head>
<body>
<ul>
{% for each_line in result %}
<p>{{ each_line }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<p>
I'm supposed to be printed</p>
</body>
</html>
```

From browser output :

> This is the result page to User
>
> I'm supposed to be printed

From Linux prompt :

> [10/Jun/2013 04:41:11] "GET /redirects HTTP/1.1" 200 727 [10/Jun/2013
>   04:41:14] "GET /choice?selection=shortcuts HTTP/1.1" 200 817 The URL
>   is not in the right format The URL is not in the right format
>   [10/Jun/2013 04:41:18] "POST /shortcuts.conf HTTP/1.1" 200 125

So now my question, why the Message `The URL is not in the right format` is not getting displayed on browser rather it displays in Linux prompt. Please help. Thanks

Comment: you should read up on django form validation

Comment: @karthikr  thanks for your reply. django forms help me in validation part, but if it is something else. Say, I have a script to take a file backup, making changes to a file with the inputs provided, how can this be done. All I want is to print the script output in User's browser

Comment: You can do that in the view method itself. Get the form, validate, process it and respond to the request

Comment: I tried with the below.
    `def shortcuts_process(request):
        if 'source' in request.POST and 'destination' in request.POST and request.POST['source'] and request.POST['destination']:
                result=take_backup()
                return render_to_response('result.html', {'result':result})`
But I could not see any result in my browser. Rather I can see the information in the Linux prompt[whilst running the manage.py runserver]

Answer (score 0):

Whatever string you want to display in the browser, return it in the HttpResponse.

You could try something like:

```
#validation.py
def validate(url1, url2):
    # perform validation here
    if valid:
        return "urls are valid"
    else:
        return "urls are invalid"


#views.py
def shortcuts_process(request):
    print request.POST
    url1 = request.POST.get('url1', '')
    url2 = request.POST.get('url2'. '')
    return HttpResponse(validate(url1, url2))
```

Hope that helps.
For form validation, please refer to Chapter 7 in the django book (http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html)

Comment: Thanks krthkr. But how to achieve the below.
Say `validate()` has got two print statements. How do you put both the prints in the browser ?

Comment: Send the data to the template. `datadict = {'statement1':'wheels of fortune', 'statement2':'all hail brassica prime'} render_to_response('template.html', datadict)`

Comment: @limelights this helps if my message is in view.py, so that I can create the template. Here I have got the message in my module. Say `validation.py` has got `print "Validation in progress" .. .. print "URLs are valid"` How can this be added into the Template.

Comment: you can just send the message from your `validation.py` to your `views.py`. `from validation import validator` and then `message = validator(url1, url2)` and lastly `datadict = {....}`.

Comment: that sound good. Let me try that and come back.. :)
Is it not possible to stream these output in the User browser. By this template way, we acquire all the output, put that in the html and then display. so we missing the real time output isn't it. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: You are correct that it's not streaming the messages back to the user, however I would take small steps. Start with this and get it working and then work on your realtimeyness.

Comment: @limelights As per your comments, I have tried and updated my question. Can you please help me from it.

Comment: How does your `process_input(src, desti)` look?

Comment: it simply calls another function validate_url() `def validate_url(url):
        parse=urlparse.urlsplit(url)
        if not parse.scheme == "http" or not parse.netloc:
                print "The URL is not in the right format "`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.. I managed to get the answer.
Rather having my function `validate_url` to `print` the values, changing it to `return` has given me the desired result.

I'm being so dumb to find this out. Failure is the stepping stone of Success !! :O)